# Getting Javascript Generated Values to Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I need some help, I'm really stuck with this problem, I have this javascript code, which adds new rows to my DataTable onClick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRow(o){
        var p=o.parentNode.parentNode;
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    }

    function addRow()
    {
        var table = document.getElementById("datatable"),
            newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
            cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
            cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
            cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),

            name = document.getElementById("form").value,
            amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

            delete1 = delete1 = '<input type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">';

        cell1.innerHTML = name;
        cell2.innerHTML = amount;
        cell3.innerHTML = delete1;

        findTotal();
    }

    function findTotal(){
        var arr = document.querySelectorAll("#datatable td:nth-child(2)");
        var tot=0;

        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            var enter_value = Number(arr[i].textContent)
            if(enter_value)
                tot += Number(arr[i].textContent);
            }
            document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
        }
    </script>
```

`<td>`s are gerated as expected. As you can see in the this picture on the browsers developer tool.

How would I save these `td`s to python?

Here's a bit of my HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-sm">
    <div class="container" id = "contact">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="h1">
                    Accountable Form 51 <small>Made easier</small></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="display: inline-block;">
            <div class="well well-sm">
            <form action="{{ url_for('addrec') }}"  method=post>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="display: inline-block; ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                O.R Number</label>
                            <br>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user-list-alt"><input type="hidden" name="OR" value="{{receiptno}}">
                              <br>
                              <h1>#{{receiptno}}</h1></span><br>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                                Payor</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "payor" id="payor" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required="required" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">
                                Nature of Payment</label>
                                <div id="RadioGroup">
                                <br>
                                <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod"  checked="checked" value="CASH"> Cash<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="CHECK"> Check<br>

                                <div id="PaymentsCHECK" class="desc" style="display: none;">
                                <br>
                                Drawee Bank<br><input type="text" name="dbank"><br>
                                Account No.<br><input type="text" name="dNum"><br>
                                Date Issued<br><input type="text" name="dDate"><br>
                                Account Name<br><input type="text" name="dName"><br>
                                </div>


                                <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="MONEY"> Money Order<br>

                                <div id="PaymentsMONEY" class="desc" style="display: none;">
                                <br>
                                Money Order No.<br><input type="text" name="dbank">
                                </div> 

                                </div>

                        </div> <!-- FORM GROUP END -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Memo</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="25" required="required"
                                placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>

          <div class="col-md-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                        Submit Form</button>
                          <br>
                    </div>
          </div>
                    </div><!-- FIRST COL6 END -->
              </div><br><br><br><br><!-- ROW END -->

              </form>

              <form>

              <div class="col-md-5" style="display: inline-block; ">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h2>Type in Nature of Collection...</h2>
                    <form name="noc">  

                      <input class="form-control input-lg" id="form" list="languages" placeholder="Search" type="text" required>
                      <br>
                      <input class="form-control input-lg" id="amount" list="languages" placeholder="Amount" type="number" required>
                      <br>
                      <button onclick="addRow(); return false;">Add Item</button>
                    </form>


              <datalist id="languages">

                {% for row in rows %}               
                  <option value = "{{row[0]}}">
                {% endfor %}

              </datalist>
               </div> <!-- JUMBO END -->


                <h6> <label>Date:<span></span>
                </label>   {{date}}</h6>
                <h3><fieldset disabled>
                <label>Total </label>
                  <h2>₱<input type = "text" name = "total" id="total"></h2>
                </fieldset></h3>

                </div><!-- COL5 END -->


<!-- </div> --><!-- REMAIN OR NOT? DEPENDS ON DEBUG PROCESS LATER -->


<div class="col-md-6" style="display: inline-block;">
      <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Nature of Collection</h2>
      </div>
      <div>

<!-- ACCUMULATION TABLE STARTS -->
      <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Nature of Collection</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th></th>

    </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
        </tr>     
</tbody>

</table>
<!-- </form> --> <!-- CHECK LATER -->


<datalist id="languages">
            {% for row in rows %}
            <option value={{row[0]}}></option>
            {% endfor %}
</datalist>

          </div>

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my full Python code which is suppsoed to receive the input in this problem:

```
@app.route('/addrec',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def addrec():

   if g.user:
        if request.method == 'POST':

#UPPER PANE

            payor = request.form['payor']

            receiptno = request.form['OR']
            paymentmethod = request.form['paymentmethod']
            naive_dt = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            collectiondate = naive_dt = datetime.now() 
            message = request.form['message']
#LOWER PANE
            url_to_scrape = 'http://localhost:5000/form'
            r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
            nature = []
            for table_row in soup.select("table.inmatesList tr"):
              cells = table_row.findAll('td')
              if len(cells) > 0:
                nature = cells[0].text.strip()
                natureamt = cells[1].text.strip()
                nature = {'nature': nature, 'nature': natureamt}
                nature_list.append(nature)
            ent = Entry(receiptno, payor,officer, paymentmethod, collectiondate,message, nature_list)
            add_entry(ent)
            actions="Applied"

            return redirect(url_for('form'))

   return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

As you can see I already tried scraping but it just loads forever. Is there any way I can get this? I separated my HTML into 2 parts. UPPER PANE and LOWER PANE. UPPER pane gets input for the basic input does and the LOWER PANE has a table and its cells are generated by an oNClick function.

So why did I separate it into two forms? This is because it gets complicated for the Lower Pane. For example, I click ADD ENTRY, instead of adding an entry its just reloads the whole website and nothing happens.

If you have an easier/cleaner/better way to do this other than scraping please do help.

[image]

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle with your working code?